# Java records validation anotation

Tags: java, record, java-14

I have old POJO with valid annotation:

```
public class SomeData {

    @NotNull(message = "Data not be null")
    private String data;

    public FormData(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public String getData() {
        return data;
    }

   public String setData(String data) {
        this.data = data
    }
    
}
```

But know I have `records`

```
public record SomeData(String data) {}
```

How I can add annotation in records?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can do like that:

```
public record SomeData(@NotNull(message = "Data not be null") String data) {}
```

Comment: That is not allowed, unless the `@NotNull` annotation class is defined with a [target](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/annotation/Target.html) that includes [ElementType.RECORD_COMPONENT](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/annotation/ElementType.html#RECORD_COMPONENT).  Existing libraries’ annotation classes will need to be updated.

Comment: @VGR annotation target locations are not mutual exclusive. A record component declaration still is a type use.

Comment: @Holger Oops, my mistake, you’re right.  The JEP actually says “Declaration annotations are permitted on record components if they are applicable to record components, parameters, fields, or methods.”